# Number of sales relative to historical date in previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database containing sales transactions. These are in the following (simplified) format:

```
sales_id | customer_id | sales_date | number_of_units | total_price
```

The goal for my query is for each of these transactions, to get the number of sales that this specific customer_id made before the current record, during the whole history of this database, but also during the 365 days before the current record.

Lifetime sales works right now, but the last 365 days part has me stuck. My query right now can identify IF a record had at least one sale in the previous 365 days, and I do it like so:

```
SELECT sales_id ,customer_id,sales_date,number_of_units,total_price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY sales_date ASC) as 'LifeTimeSales' ,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,sales_date,LAG(sales_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY sales_date ASC)) > -365
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'Last365Sales'
 FROM sales_db
```

+ some non-important WHERE clauses. After which I aggregate the result of this query in some other ways.

But this does not tell me if this purchase is for example the 4th sale in the previous 365 days of a customer.

Note:
This is a query that runs daily on the full database with 6 million records and growing. I drop and recreate this table right now, which is obviously not efficient. Updating the table when new sales come in would be ideal, but right now this is not possible to create. Any ideas?

Some test data:

```
sales_id,customer_id,sales_date,number_of_units,total_price
1001,2001,2016-01-01,1,86
1002,2001,2016-08-01,3,98
1003,2001,2017-06-01,2,87
1004,2002,2017-06-01,2,15
```

+ expected result:

```
sales_id,customer_id,sales_date,number_of_units,total_price,LifeTimeSales,Last365Sales
1001,2001,2016-01-01,1,86,0,0
1002,2001,2016-08-01,3,98,1,1
1003,2001,2017-06-01,2,87,2,1
1004,2002,2017-06-01,2,15,0,0
```

Comment: Table DDL + sample data + expected result would probably give you an answer in a minutes...

Comment: Try `<= 365` im not sure but i have trouble with this type of query myself i get my signs mixed up ahah it might be the other way and you may need to add a specific date diff **EDITITED**

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I've added sample data + expected result.

Comment: @connorg98 that doesn't do it. Then it only checks if there was a sale more then 365 days in the past.

Comment: Your question confuses me. Do you want the count of sales done before a sale? Or do you want to enumerate the sales? But than there can be only one enumeration for one customer in one column. But you want it somehow relative to a row. But there is more than row, so more than one enumeration...

Comment: @stickybit What I want is the number of times a customer has made a sale before the sale in the record I'm currently referencing. So in the example data, for sale 1003, I get '2' since the customer has made two sales previous to the one with id 1003. However, I also want to know how many of the sales previous to 1003 have been in the 365 days previous to the date of sale 1003, which is only sale 1002 so, since 1001 was more then 365 days before the date that 1003 took place.

Answer (score 1):

For the count of sales before a sale you could use correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT s1.sales_id,
       s1.customer_id,
       s1.sales_date,
       s1.number_of_units,
       s1.total_price,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM sales_db s2
               WHERE s2.customer_id = s1.customer_id
                     AND s2.sales_date <= s1.sales_date) - 1 lifetimesales,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM sales_db s2
               WHERE s2.customer_id = s1.customer_id
                     AND s2.sales_date <= s1.sales_date
                     AND s2.sales_date >= dateadd(day, s1.sales_date, -356)) - 1 last365sales
       FROM sales_db s1;
```

(I used `s2.sales_date <= s1.sales_date` and then subtracted 1 from the reuslt, so that multiple sales on the same day, if such data exists, are also counted. But as this also counts the sale of the current row, it has to be decremented by 1.)

Comment: Okay I tried this yesterday, and it works however it performs too slow for my database. After running 3 full hours, it only retrieved 600 rows, and the total number should be around 2 million, so unfortunately it will not work on my case. Probably not ideal that there's no index on sales_date or customer_id...

Comment: @JeroendeK: Yes, an index could help. Try one on `(customer_id, sales_date)` (both columns in one index) and one the other way round, `(sales_date, customer_id)`. See wich one is better.

Answer (score 0):

I create report view where all required fields are available.
Select all that you need:

```
with all_history_statistics as 
(select customer_id, sales_id, sales_date, number_of_units, total_price,
    max(sales_date) over (partition by customer_id order by (select null)) as last_sale_date,
    count(sales_id) over (partition by customer_id order by (select null)) total_number_of_sales,
    count(sales_id) over (partition by customer_id order by sales_date asc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) number_of_sales_for_current_date,
    sum(number_of_units) over (partition by customer_id order by (select null)) total_number_saled_units,
    sum(number_of_units) over (partition by customer_id order by sales_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) number_saled_units_for_current_date,
    sum(total_price) over (partition by customer_id order by (select null)) as total_earned,
    sum(total_price) over (partition by customer_id order by sales_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) earned_for_current_date)
from sales_db),
with last_year_statistics as 
(select customer_id, sales_id, sales_date, number_of_units, total_price,
    max(sales_date) over (partition by customer_id order by (select null)) as last_sale_date,
    count(sales_id) over (partition by customer_id order by (select null)) total_number_of_sales,
    count(sales_id) over (partition by customer_id order by sales_date asc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) number_of_sales_for_current_date,
    sum(number_of_units) over (partition by customer_id order by (select null)) total_number_saled_units,
    sum(number_of_units) over (partition by customer_id order by sales_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) number_saled_units_for_current_date,
    sum(total_price) over (partition by customer_id order by (select null)) as total_earned,
    sum(total_price) over (partition by customer_id order by sales_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) earned_for_current_date)
from sales_db)
select <specify list of fields which you need>
from all_history_statistics t1 inner join last_year_statistics
on t1.customer_id = t2.cutomer_id 
;
```

Comment: @JeroendeK sorry, I can miss this. Can you clarify which expected information this query doesn't return?

Comment: The last_year_statistics and the all_history_statistics are the same, so it doesn't give me the relative sales.

Comment: @JeroendeK it's my bad. Sorry, I'll think how to improve my answer and try to answer in a short time.